# How to remove [style="display: table-row"] added by tablesorter to each row in the table?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

I want to set child rows in the table collapsible. It is possible using the bootstrap `collapse`. But it does not work since `tablesorter` adds somewhere `style="display: table-row"`, so it is visible always.

Where could I remove this css style?

Comment: Have you tried `$(".tablesorter tr").css("display", "");` ?

Comment: yep, but it is just a workaround

Comment: @static Do you have any coding, or maybe a live example? I looked at examples using tablesoter online, none of which add `display:table-row` inline.

Comment: look for all demos on the official site (e.g.: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html)

Comment: @JoshC, it's not in the documentation's HTML window, but if you look at the generated source, it is added. The function in the js that adds it is a tricky one, too.

Comment: @Onimusha: the problem is, if I use a filter, which hides (`display: none`) unmatched rows - after resetting the filter `tablesorter` adds `display: table-row` back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a css class like this

```
.invisible-table tr {
    display: none !important;
}
```

and then just add/remove the invisible-table class to tablesorter as you wish.

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I didn't think about using !important. This is a quality fix.

Comment: it is more reliable workaround, but still - not more than a hack, I still add and than override the style instead of just do nothing (if I could remove the adding of `display: table-row` from the lib).

Comment: This is better than a regular hack, because you know it will work with later versions of the lib as well (of course, if you put this rule outside of the lib's css). Flaws of libraries are solved with hacks. The best you can do is to put your hack outside the library. By the way I cannot name many cases when you solve your problem by doing nothing as described here: "I still add and than override the style instead of just do nothing".

Comment: I don't really like the `!important` thing, but for now its really the simpliest solution, which works well: it also solves the mentioned problem with filtering

Comment: I believe you are right and it is not nice to use the !important in general. However, in this particular case it is used to prevent the symptoms of a library bug.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround in your comments posted by @Onimusha is your best option. The tablesorter code is adding that style inline to the DOM elements of "TR" programmatically. The only other option would be to edit the source of the tablesorter javascript to remove that inline style addition, and compile into your own custom tablesorter-min.js

I suggest the workaround as the elegant solution.

```
  $(".tablesorter tr").css("display", "");
```

Comment: The tablesorter code is adding the style using variables that depend on other variables. It won't be easy to modify. I also would use Onimusha's solution. It's fast, elegant and will work.

Comment: the problem is, if I use a filter, which hides (`display: none`) unmatched rows - after resetting the filter `tablesorter` adds `display: table-row` back again.